# WPF Animate property of child without using Name

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, element, children

I'm trying to create a storyboard in XAML that animates a property of one of the child elements of an element which raises an event. But I can't seem to get it to work without using Names, which is something I can't really do in this specific situation.

I'm basically trying something like this (much simplified of course):

```
   <Canvas>
      <Canvas.Triggers>
         <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
               <BeginStoryboard>
                  <Storyboard>
                     <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Children[0].(Canvas.Left)" From="0" To="400" />
                  </Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
         </EventTrigger>
      </Canvas.Triggers>

      <Button Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20">A</Button>
      <Button Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="20">B</Button>
   </Canvas>
```

Any ideas on how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Providing that the `UIElement` you are indexing in the animation exists (i.e. already present on the `Canvas`) then you can do the following:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas">
    <Button x:Name="btn" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20">A</Button>
    <Button Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="20">B</Button>
    <Canvas.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=MyCanvas, Path=Children[0]}"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)" From="0" To="400" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Canvas.Triggers>
</Canvas>
```

Notice how I have moved the addition of the Buttons above the `Trigger`. If the Buttons are below the `Trigger` as in your question, trying to access `Children[0]` will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because there are no children at this point.

Answer (score 1):

To use the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` in the animation, it should always be a dependency property. `Children` property gets a `UIElementCollection` of child elements of this `Panel` (`Canvas`). Therefore, the following construction `Children [n]` return `UIElement`, which should lead to a certain type, to access its dependency property.

This can be done in the code as follows:

```
Button MyButton = (Button)MyCanvas.Children[0];

MessageBox.Show(MyButton.Width.ToString());
```

All of these actions *missing* in the animation by default, this is your construction will not work.

I propose to create animations in the code where this conversion possible.

To demonstrate this, I created a `Canvas`, in the event `Loaded` having registered animation. Element number is set via an attached dependency property (of course, the example can be implemented in various ways). Below is my example:

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyCanvas x:Name="MyCanvas" local:ClassForAnimation.Children="1">
        <Button Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="20">A</Button>
        <Button Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="20">B</Button>
    </local:MyCanvas>
</Grid>
```

`Code behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       
}

public class MyCanvas : Canvas 
{
    public MyCanvas() 
    {
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyCanvas_Loaded);
    }

    private void MyCanvas_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyCanvas myCanvas = sender as MyCanvas;

        // Get No. of children
        int children = ClassForAnimation.GetChildren(myCanvas);

        // Get current Button for animation
        Button MyButton = (Button)myCanvas.Children[children];

        if (myCanvas != null)
        {
            DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();

            doubleAnimation.From = 0;
            doubleAnimation.To = 400;

            MyButton.BeginAnimation(Button.WidthProperty, doubleAnimation);
        }
    }
}

public class ClassForAnimation : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty;

    public static void SetChildren(DependencyObject DepObject, int value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value);
    }

    public static int GetChildren(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (int)DepObject.GetValue(ChildrenProperty);
    }

    static ClassForAnimation()
    {
        PropertyMetadata MyPropertyMetadata = new PropertyMetadata(0);

        ChildrenProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Children",
                                                            typeof(int),
                                                            typeof(ClassForAnimation),
                                                            MyPropertyMetadata);
    }       
}
```

`Note:` Access to the items in the `Canvas` should only be done in the event `Loaded`, or when it ended. Otherwise, the items are not available because they are not loaded.